# Changing Button Text with Case? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

i need some help. trying to change button text with  case statement but nothing is working.

My code:

```
Select case Text
Case btn_1.text = "Start"
btn_1.text = "Stop"
msgbox("I Started")

Case btn_1.text = "Stop"
btn_1.text = "Start"
msgbox("I Stopped")
```

Comment: @HarshBaid: actually this is a very good use case for a `Select...Case`. The text on the button is pre-defined and cannot be changed by the user.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it can. i am changing the button text with the corrected Code. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) is malformed. Have a look at the linked MSDN page for an explanation.

```
Select Case btn_1.Text
    Case "Start"
        btn_1.Text = "Stop"
        MessageBox.Show("I Started")
    Case "Stop"
        btn_1.Text = "Start"
        MessageBox.Show("I Stopped")
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is somehow incorrect..

You should do it like this.

```
Dim text As String = btn_1.Text

Select Case text
  Case "Start"
      btn_1.Text = "Stop"
  Case "Stop"
      btn_1.Text = "Start"
End Select
```

or better to use if statement like this

```
Dim text As String = btn_1.Text
If text.Equals("Start")
   btn_1.Text = "Stop"
Else
   btn_1.Text = "Start"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! yes is was incorrect, i was missing the dim statement . Thank you once more. dont know why but my question was down voted. Sad